# JSON object to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

//JSONParser.class

public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jobj = null;
static String json = "";
public JSONParser(){

}
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url){
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            is = httpentity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");   

                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                try {
                    jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return jobj;

}
```

}

//MainActivity.class

```
class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://www.mywebsite.com/event/list_event_android.php");

        // check your log for json response
        Log.d("Login attempt", jobj.toString());

        try {
            name = jobj.getString("events");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return name;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String name){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

//Below is my current output

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Demo Event",
            "descr": "This is a demo",
            "date_d": "12/27/2014",
            "time_t": "",
            "images": "http://www.adagioinfotech.com/event/uploads/event/demo.png",
            "images1": "http://www.adagioinfotech.com/event/uploads/event/demo1.png",
            "location": "Ernakulam",
            "publish": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Flower Show",
            "descr": "xfvslkdfvsw fvgersdgvel fgvmerlkgjer fgertgkjerltgf dfrgergt",
            "date_d": "12/29/2014",
            "time_t": "",
            "images": "http://www.adagioinfotech.com/event/uploads/event/demo.png",
            "images1": "http://www.adagioinfotech.com/event/uploads/event/demo1.png",
            "location": "Thodupuzha",
            "publish": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Cultural Event",
            "descr": "sfsdnfkjn sdfrelegkrg fdgvlkgvjmer fdgbelkrek dferlkgelrk dfgerge",
            "date_d": "12/30/2014",
            "time_t": "",
            "images": "http://www.adagioinfotech.com/event/uploads/event/demo.png",
            "images1": "http://www.adagioinfotech.com/event/uploads/event/demo1.png",
            "location": "Idukki",
            "publish": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to display only values inside the name field...Is there any method to do so??? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`events` tag is your `JSONArray` not a `String`. You need to change this

```
name = jobj.getString("events");
```

to

```
JSONArray nameArray = jobj.getJSONArray("events");
```

***EDIT:***

You can get your all value from your `events` jsonarray. Like

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length(); ++i) {
 JSONObject arrayObject = nameArray.getJSONObject(i);
 String name = arrayObject.getString("name"); // Same for as other strings.
}
```

You need to make a global variable for your `JSONObject` for this

```
  JSONObject arrayObject = nameArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

or make a String name variable global and access it in `onPostExecute()` method. Like

```
  textView.setText(name);
```

Comment: ok...i changed...how to select only a single value from json.

Comment: how to display String name in a textview inside onPostExecute ? my textview id is tv3.

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String name){
         tv3.setText(name);
     }  //is it correct

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonString = "Here goes your JSON String";
```

Now, the first thing you have is curly braces so you need to make a JSONObject from the String.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jSonString);
```

Now, it contains an array (because '[]' are used) called events.

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("events");
```

Now, traverse the array :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject arrayObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    arrayObject.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: how to display arrayObject.getString("names"); in a textview ?

Comment: textView.setText(arrayObject.getString("names"));

Comment: @ShivamVerma the name of the string is "name" not "names".

Comment: Lolwut. Seriously, that's the problem ?

Comment: Its not a problem. I just suggested to you that correct your string dude because i am not stupid.

Answer (score -2):

You need to iterate in Json array. There is more tutorial [Json Parse](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)